# System.log shows CACHE/BACKEND/CLASS/NAME.php

Tags: magento-1.9

I got the following error in my system.log in Magento

Who has an idea how to solve this one?

```
2016-12-07T11:57:07+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(CACHE/BACKEND/CLASS/NAME.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-12-07T11:57:07+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(CACHE/BACKEND/CLASS/NAME.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-12-07T11:57:07+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'CACHE/BACKEND/CLASS/NAME.php' for inclusion (include_path='app/code/local:app/code/community:app/code/core:lib:.:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/php')  in lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-12-07T11:57:08+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(CACHE/BACKEND/CLASS/NAME.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-12-07T11:57:08+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(CACHE/BACKEND/CLASS/NAME.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-12-07T11:57:08+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'CACHE/BACKEND/CLASS/NAME.php' for inclusion (include_path='app/code/local:app/code/community:app/code/core:lib:.:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/php')  in lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed while changing from Redis to Memcached